# How to extract UUID from a uri using Regular Expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url string

```
http://apistaging.yoolk.com/listings/F7B519E8-135C-43D0-A35F-764B582EDC48?domain_name=cambodiastaging.yoolk.com&display=basic
```

I would like to get only the uuid `F7B519E8-135C-43D0-A35F-764B582EDC48` from this url by using regular expression in Javascript. How could I do so? Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = 'http://apistaging.yoolk.com/listings/F7B519E8-135C-43D0-A35F-764B582EDC48?domain_name=cambodiastaging.yoolk.com&display=basi',

    matches = url.match(/listings\/([A-F\d-]+)\?/),

    UUID = matches[1];

console.log(UUID); // F7B519E8-135C-43D0-A35F-764B582EDC48
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zH4uU/).

Answer (score 14):

```
/((\w{4,12}-?)){5}/.exec(URL)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with splits.

```
var uri = 'http://apistaging.yoolk.com/listings/F7B519E8-135C-43D0-A35F-764B582EDC48?domain_name=cambodiastaging.yoolk.com&display=basic'    
uri.split('?')[0].split('/')[4]
```